# How can i save current context to local variable in Javasccript

Tags: javascript

i try to save current context to local/global variable and use this in event "showModal". When i am handling event, i get $this as this of window object. And i need take context and call function. Can anybody help me?

Code:

```
var Modal = (function() {

    $this = this;
    var el = '.modal';

    return {
        init: function() {
            $(window).on('showModal', function(e, data) {
                $this.getData(data.controller, data.action, data.id);
            });
        },
        getData: function(controller, action, id) {
            var html = $.ajax({
                url: '/' + controller + '/' + action + '/' + id ? id : '',
                async: false
            }).responseText;
            this.render(html);
        },
        render: function(html) {
            $(el).html(html);
            $(el).modal();

            this.event();
        },
        event: function() {

        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: You want `$this` refer to the object that you directly return. Why did you expect that `this` would refer to the object that isn't evern created yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `this`, simply drop the functions inside the scope, and export them at the end:

```
var Modal = (function() {

  var el = '.modal';

  function init() {
    $(window).on('showModal', function(e, data) {
      getData(data.controller, data.action, data.id);
    });        
  }

  function getData(controller, action, id) {
    var html = $.ajax({
      url: '/' + controller + '/' + action + '/' + id ? id : '',
      async: false
    }).responseText;
    render(html);
  }

  function render(html) {
    $(el).html(html);
    $(el).modal();
    event();
  }

  function event() {

  }

  return {init:init, getData:getData, render:render, event:event}
})();
```

Or better yet, make a jQuery plugin.